# php curl doesent work on fb graph with https

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code :

```
$handle=curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=***');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($handle);

echo $content;
```

and it returns nothing, I think the problem is because the https because when i change to a link with http it works.
but when i use https://www.google.com/ as the link it still works, so Im not sure what the problem is but i think facebook is blocking something..

please help ? i tryed checking if there is an error and it dident give me any errors,
when I checked (I think print_r) it gave me this :

```
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 1.9E-5
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
```

please help ! I searched everywhere and nothing helped..

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your curl request as seen above with status coce = 0

try this func to see what the error is.

string curl_error ( resource $ch ) Returns a clear text error message for the last cURL operation.

most likely, its because of incorrect url string. make sure you encode the query string values before making the request with that url.

Comment: it gave me the error "couldn't connect to host" how do i fix it ?

Comment: and what do you meen by " make sure you encode the query string values before making the request with that url." how do I do it ?

Comment: first, check the error msg from curl i.e. curl_error($ch); after that, if erro is due to malformed url, check the url. query string is what you pass after the ?, for eg www.mysite.com?param1=value1&param2=value2. here value1 should be urlencode($value1). same for other query string values. if you dont encode those query string values, your curl wont work properly.

Comment: when I do curl_error($ch) it gives me the error : couldn't connect to host and the urlencode doesent help...